dbt run appending schema name from both profiles.yml and dbt_project.yml
I have a folder within model and my files within the subfolder. When I run the model, it creates a schema and table in my destination but the schema name is not getting picked from dbt_projects.yml rather it appends both schema name from profiles and dbt_project
profiles.yml
profile_name:
  outputs:
    dev:
      account: XX
      database: XX
      password: XX
      role: SYSADMIN
      schema: openair 
      threads: 1
      type: snowflake
      user: XX
      warehouse: DBT_WH
  target: dev

dbt_project.yml
models:
  +transient: false
  profile_name:
    openair:
      +database: XX
      +schema: openair
      +materialized: table

When I run my models from openair folder, it creates a schema called openair_openair rather than just openair.
I have a similar setup for other source systems and it runs fine, not sure what's causing this. How can I have dbt pick schema name from dbt_project.yml only?

As the dbt documentation points out here, the expected dbt behaviour is to append the {{ schema }} into the {{ target.schema }} (separated by an underscore) when both are defined.
In your case:

your target.schema is defined in your profiles.yml as openair
and your schema is defined in your dbt_project.yml as openair again

Hence, the behaviour of dbt is to append schema into target.schema as openair_openair.

So, how to override this behaviour if you want to override the schema for just one model?

here are the docs: https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/custom-schemas
